# Docker on windows server 2012r2

Tags: windows, docker

Confused about one thing. So does running the docker engine on windows server 2012 work? Or is it just that the container OS needs to be 2016 or Nano?

So docker engine on 2012, running a container with 2016/Nano

Answer (score 10):

From https://forums.docker.com/t/windows-server-2012-r2/24267 :
"No, Windows Server 2016 is required for running native Windows containers. The kernel containerization primitives are only available starting with WS 2016."